# How to search an inner class?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have these classes.

```
class Author{
    Person person
}


class Person{
    String lastName
    String firstName
    String middleName
}
```

I'd like to query Person and Author.

```
def persons = Person.findAllByLastNameiLike("${a}")
```

but it seems I can't do

```
def authors = Author.findAllByPerson(persons)
```

Any ideas how I'd do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code shown above does not work

```
def authors = Author.findAllByPerson(persons)
```

because `findAllBy*` works with a single object, not a collection. To find all authors where the `Person` is any one of those contained in `persons` use either HQL or a criteria query. For example an (untested) HQL query would look something like:

```
Author.executeQuery("""
    FROM Author a
    WHERE a.person IN (:people)""", [people: persons])
```